# Macro Find Blank cells and Replace

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns of data, A and B.  I want to find blank cells in column B and then copy data from corresponding cell in column A if A is not also blank.

Comment: Would there really be any issues if you copied a blank cell from `A` to a blank cell in `B`?

Comment: no - i just dont want to overwrite content in B if it already exists

Answer (score 1):

I'd use SpecialCells:

```
Sub fillblanks()
Dim rngBlanks As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim cl As Range

Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns(2)
Set rngBlanks = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
For Each cl In rngBlanks.Cells
    With cl
        If (.Value = "") And (.Offset(0, -1).Value <> "") Then
            .Value = .Offset(0, -1).Value
        End If
    End With
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Fun, playing with my answer vs yours, I figured I'd check your code also by removing the line that checks for a blank in the offset, This actually slowed down your sub by almost 33%. Makes sense because a check if much faster then a modification to a cell. But I didn't realize it would slow it down 33%. Not sure if you knew it would be faster when you wrote it or it you were simply following the Askers guidelines but I found it interesting. I'll uploaded the sample workbook if your interested in playing with it.

Comment: I've Preemptively uploaded the sample workbook [Here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/b8sxpkgvsizak60/Book1.xlsm) .

Comment: I was just following the guidelines, without even thinking about performance, but it does make sense -- any change to the worksheet objects is time consuming.

Comment: The part that confuses me then is why mine, which modifies the entire column, twice is just about 285% faster then yours, just though you'd be interested in the findings.

Comment: You're only making one call to `Columns("B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)` range object. I'm making multiple calls, i.e., to each `cl` range. Technically, I think you are only performing two operations (`.FormulaR1C1` and `Value`), whereas mine is performing one operation (`.Value`) but multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub Sample2()

On Error Resume Next

With Columns("B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]"
    .Value = .Value
End With

End Sub
```

This doesn't do EXACTLY as you ask as if does not skip a blank cell if the cell in A is blank, This is because I fail to see why replacing and blank with another blank would be an issue. if it is there is a very easy fix by simply modifying  `.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]"` to take into account the blanks.

Answer (score 1):

No need for VBA. Select ColumnB, HOME > Editing, Find & Select, Go To Special..., Select Blanks (only),

```
=
```

<kbd>←</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.